# User answered their own question, then deleted their (seemingly valid) answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706590/low-level-select-poll-to-read-from-subprocess) question, and was watching for an answer.

Eventually, the user answered their own question, but then 4 minutes after answering it, they deleted their answer.  Their (deleted) answer sounds valid to me, and no one else has answered.  I posted a comment on the question asking if the user would consider undeleting their answer, and someone else (under 10K) posted that they'd like to know the results.  In almost 3 days, the user has not responded at all.

I was considering copying their answer verbatim and posting it as a community wiki with a line attributing the answer to the OP.  But it occurred to me that that could be against their wishes - after all, they must have had a reason for deleting their answer in the first place, and I don't know the topic enough to be certain that their answer was right.

Should I repost the answer as a community wiki, or just leave the answer deleted?

For the <10k users, here's the answer in question:

> I figured it out: apparently the proc.stdout stream object is
>   automatically doing its own internal buffering, despite the bufsize =
>   0 argument passed to subprocess.Popen. The stream object seems to
>   automatically buffer data available for reading on the pipe's stdout
>   file descriptor behind the scenes.
>
> So basically, I can't use os.read to read directly from the underlying
>   descriptor, because the proc.stdout BufferedReader is automatically
>   doing it's own buffering by reading from the underlying descriptor. To
>   get this working as I want, I can simply call
>   proc.stdout.read(READ_SIZE) instead of os.read(fd, READ_SIZE)
>   directly, after poll() indicates there is data to be read. That works
>   as expected.

Comment: Maybe their answer was wrong from their perspective?

Comment: If you don't actually know if the answer is right or not, why not simply let someone who *does* know if the answer is right or not make that call?  If someone else sees the answer and *is* confident that it is the correct answer to the question, then they can post it under their own name (with attribution, of course).

Comment: If I post it as an answer (cw), it's still showing a valid step in their research, and over time, if it's wrong, the community could downvote it or improve the answer.  It seems wrong to let others miss out on learning from what the user wrote.

Comment: A user has a right to delete their own answer if they want to, and deleting it means that they no longer want it associated with them. Therefore, if you did decide to repost it, you should *not* attribute it to them. You still can't plagiarize it, of course, so you'll have to put it in your own words.

Comment: @CodyGray Creating a derived work from someone else's work still requires attribution.

Comment: Normally, yes. Not if they've deleted it. That means they don't want to be associated with the content anymore. In effect, they've delicensed it; CC by-SA no longer applies. Reposting it in your own answer with their name is tantamount to denying their right to delete answers.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein It's not particularly useful as research without knowing why it doesn't work.  If the OP explained why the solution doesn't solve the problem, then it could be edited in to the *question*, but until the author further clarifies why that solution doesn't work, I think it'd just make the question *worse*.  You shouldn't just go around posting answers that you're pretty sure are wrong (but don't even have the expertise to judge at all) and simply *hoping* that people will realize why the subtly wrong answer is in fact wrong.  The OP clearly took a while to realize it, after all.

Comment: @CodyGray That's simply false.  They *haven't* revoked the license.  In fact, they *can't* revoke the license.  The license is *irrevocable*.  They couldn't revoke it *even if they wanted to*.  Per the licenses terms, they're allowed to anonymize their contributions *if the specifically request it*, but that's not revoking the licence, and also not something that they've done. "Reposting it in your own answer with their name is tantamount to denying their right to delete answers."  That's correct; when they applied the licence to the content *they gave up their right to delete it*.

Comment: @Servy I'm not quite that bad - I'm fairly certain their answer is right.  I don't know why they deleted it.  That it's not right (or not right in all situations) is a possible reason, and the most likely reason I can think of for an arbitrary deletion.  If I thought it was blatantly wrong, I wouldn't want to resurrect it.  Other than that, I see your point - since it's a possible reason for deletion, it's up to the OP.

Comment: @CodyGray Obviously, deleting doesn't disassociate the user from the post, since anyone 10k+ still sees the association.  If it was a legal issue as you described, no one would see the associated name.  I could easily accept that that's their intent on an ethical level; then it becomes a debate over the ethics of their decision vs the ethics of plagiarizing.

Comment: Actually, the license's terms don't say anything about anonymization, either. But this really doesn't need to be turned into a legal issue. It's a fundamental decency issue, covered well by common sense. I should have the right to retract something I've posted here, and you should respect that right by not continuing to plaster my name on it.

Comment: @CodyGray No, again, you *don't* have that right.  You *specifically* gave up that right when you applied the CC-Wiki license.  If you don't want to give up your right to remove some content then *don't apply a licence to it that specifically gives up that right*.  That you *wish* that people have the right to something doesn't change the *unambiguous fact* that they don't.  You are of course more than welcome to not exercise *your* right to re-publish this user's contributions (with attribution), but you don't have the ability to revoke anyone else's right *to* re-publish it.

Comment: The licensor is explicitly allowed to make special requests upon the licensee per the Creative Commons license. Though those requests are not legally binding, they are ethically binding, and it has always been our site policy to comply with such requests when it comes to granting users the ability to delete/retract answers. Again, I concede that I misspoke when I said that the *license* was retracted, but that doesn't change the fact that what I'm speaking of is reasonable, ethical, and long-standing site policy. What I really wish is that more people around here had common sense.

Comment: Cody has entirely too much common sense, hard to keep up with him.  An affliction that @Siler seems to suffer from as well, "you can't do it" is not often considered a useful answer at SO.  Even though it is entirely accurate.  It has to be proven beyond a shadow of a doubt, with citations.

Comment: @CodyGray SE *regularly* prevents people from deleting content, even against the wishes of the author.  People try to vandalize their own content *daily* and have such vandalism reversed, and restrictions put in place to prevent the author from continuing to apply them.  SE will often let the deleted content stay deleted *if it feels that the content isn't useful*, but any situation in which the author wants to delete the content, but other's feel it's good content, historically results in the content not being deleted (and at most anonymized up on specific request).

Comment: @CodyGray If you think that it's unethical to give up your right to delete content, then *don't give up your right to delete content*.  It's really that simple.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't realize that posting objectively false statements that actively encourage people to engage in illegal behavior was considered common sense.  It's a definition of the term I haven't heard of before.

Comment: And the only way I "don't give up [my] right to delete content" is by not posting the content in the first place. Which means I never really had the right at all. Hmm. Doesn't sound so simple. Well, good thing I never say anything foolish that I might not want permanently associated with my name.

Comment: @CodyGray In order to not give up your right to delete content you'd need to not post it *to a site that specifically requires all user-contributions to grant everyone the right to re-publish the content* (with attribution), that's right.  If you don't want the CC licence applied to your content then you'll need to post it to a site that doesn't apply such a license (whether that be your own, or some other site that has different terms for user contributions).  It's not that you never have the right to control copies of the content, it's that SE *requires users give that right up*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important not to lose good answers, but...

> ...I don't know the topic enough to be certain that their answer was right.

...if **you** can't independently verify that the answer is actually *good*, then there's no reason to resurrect it.

Comment: Makes sense, and there's no competition so you get a shiny checkmark.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted the answer because I realized my solution was not really correct.  It worked most of the time, but was still prone to losing some bytes.  After further research, I have now posted what I think is a correct answer.